# Put image on top of image React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a image in my component and I am trying to place an image on top of that. But only the first image shows, the one I am trying to place on top of it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React Native supports `zIndex`. You can give your second image a style like this `{ zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute', ... // other position style }` to put it on top of other view. 
See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#zindex for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `second Image` inside the `first one`:

```
<View style={Styles.container}>
    <View style={Styles.viewStyle}>
        <Image
            style={Styles.imageStyle}
            source={require('./Bakgrundsbild.png')} >
            <View style={Styles.logoViewStyle}>
                <Image
                    style={Styles.logoStyle}
                    source={require('./Logo.png')}
                    />
            </View>
         </Image>
     </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give ImageBackground & then give Image

```
<ImageBackground>
<Image></Image>
</ImageBackground>
```

like this